# pytrend.interest_over_time() - what does the value returned represent? 100s of searches, 1000s of seaches, 100,000s of searches?

Tags: python, pandas, google-trends

Edit: Found the answer - posted below:

I'm using pytrend.interest_over_time() to get the number of google searches for 'fires near me' during the Australian Bushfire season.  I'm trying to find out what the value returned represents.  EG - first row below for 30 Nov 2019, shows 7.  Is this 700, 7000, 70,000, 700,000?  I've searched but I can't find the information.  For context - 'Fires Near Me' was the number 1 google search term in 2019 in Australia - it's the fire mapping GIS tool supplied by RFS.

```
pytrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360, retries=2, backoff_factor=0.1)
keywords = ['fires near me', 'smoke', 'air quality']

pytrend.build_payload(
     kw_list=keywords,
     cat=0,
     timeframe='2019-09-01 2020-04-30',
     geo='AU-NSW',
     gprop='')
data = pytrend.interest_over_time()

data= data.drop(labels=['isPartial'],axis='columns')

image = data.plot(title = 'Fire in last 5 years on Google Trends ')
fig = image.get_figure()
fig.savefig('figure.png')


data.to_csv('Syd_Google_Smoke.csv', encoding='utf_8_sig')


[Screenshot of df output][1]


            fires near me   smoke   air quality  
date                 
2019-11-30        7           1          1 
2019-12-01        20          6          2 
2019-12-02        22          8          6 
2019-12-03        22          8          6  
2019-12-04        26          10         9
```

Any help appreciated - thankyou

Answer (score 2):

From Google Trends website:

Interest over time

Numbers represent search interest relative to the highest point on the chart for the given region and time. A value of 100 is the peak popularity for the term. A value of 50 means that the term is half as popular. A score of 0 means there was not enough data for this term.